# What is the App server for fatwire?

Tags: content-management-system, fatwire

Do fatwire has its own app server?
Or it use any standard app servers like **Apache tomcat**
(I dont mean jump start kit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebLogic, WebSphere, Tomcat, JBoss are all supported.

For a list of officially supported software for Oracle Web Center Sites(formerly FatWire Content Server), refer to this certification matrix : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/sites/owcs-11gr1certmatrix-1609746.xls

Prior to acquisition by Oracle, the JSK was bundled with JBoss and Tomcat server instances and it was possible to select one or the other as the deployment platform.

Now it only ships with Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, it can run on any Java EE compliant application server, but I always found it easiest to run on Tomcat since it's easier to setup and administer; and it's FoC.

From memory, the JSK used to use JBoss but was switched to use Tomcat in a later incarnation

Answer (score 0):

Fatwire hasn't its own app server but it can be deployed on Apache Tomcat, JBoss, IBM WAS, WebLogic, Sun Java Enterprise System or Oracle Application Server.

Comment: Jump start kits uses Apache Tomcat